# table dashed walking not from end to end

Tags: html, css, marquee

I create a table using dashed and how to make that dashed walked around the table form, not from end to end???
`<style="border: dashed 2px #ee3f10;padding: 15px; margin: 0; text-align: justify; line-height:23px; color: #1a356e; font-size:18px">`

Comment: `<p>` is a paragraph, not a table.

Comment: Please be clear on the question. You want a dashed bordered table?

Comment: yeah i mean that @JijoCleetus

Comment: ok, so the below shared answer is doing well. please check that.

Comment: @mas Mind removing the marquee tag from your question?

Answer (score 1):

Paragraph elements are block elements by default. A block element will take all available width.

To change that, just add `display: inline-block;` to your `p`:

```html
<p style="border: dashed 2px #ee3f10;padding: 15px; margin: 0; text-align: justify; line-height:23px; color: #1a356e; font-size:18px; display:inline-block;"> </p>
```